# Insert OUTPUT into a table with ROWLOCK

Tags: sql-server

I have a temporary table A with 100K items which I need to insert into another table B, so I insert them into table B by batches, in order not to block the table, using the below:

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @A)
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (1000) TMP 
    OUTPUT DELETED.FieldA, DELETED.FieldB
    INTO [dbo].[TableB] ([FieldA] ,[FieldB]) 
    FROM @A TMP
END
```

That works OK but I would like to know if there is a way to specify a table hint with ROWLOCK when inserting into table B?

Like this

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @A)
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (1000) TMP 
    OUTPUT DELETED.FieldA, DELETED.FieldB
    INTO [dbo].[TableB] WITH (ROWLOCK) ([FieldA] ,[FieldB]) 
    FROM @A TMP
END
```

It won't let me now.

Comment: Can you tell us why you would want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to avoid page lock when inserting to the table.